# Appending form input value to action url as path

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-routing

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost/test">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

If I type a value, let's say: 'hello' in the text input field and submit the form, the URL looks like: `http://localhost/test/?keywords=hello`.

I want the value to get appended to the action path. So basically, after the form submission the URL should look like:

```
http://localhost/test/hello
```

Comment: You might have to use *htaccess rewriterule*!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `onsubmit` attribute and set the action inside a function for example:

```
<form id="your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

function yourFunction(){
    var action_src = "http://localhost/test/" + document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value;
    var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
    your_form.action = action_src ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onsubmit` and use `jQuery` to obtain the same result.

Check the following.

HTML Code:

```
<form id = "your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
    function yourFunction(){

    var action_src = $("keywords").val();
    var your_form = $('your_form').val();

    var urlLink = "http://localhost/test/";
    urlLink = urlLink + action_src;



    your_form.action = urlLink;

}
```