# How do I pass user inputted values into a dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to allow user to specify a value then allow them to click a button a take them to a URL that was customized based on their entry.

Below is what I have so far; the only issue is for some reason my user_input data is not being passed to the URL when I click the Go button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<p>Testing</p>
</head>
<body>
<label for="Store_No">Store_No</label>
<input type = "text" id="user_input"></input>


<form action="http://XXX/XX?Store_No="+user_input>
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use dynamic variables in HTML, in the way you have used it with the line `...action="..."+user_input>`. This is not permissible HTML, you have to use JavaScript in order to render the URL location.

Comment: Do you mean by this? I can redirect to the url. http://jsfiddle.net/wp2rjzkd/

Comment: Actually, this may be a better match: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128361/appending-form-input-value-to-action-url-as-path

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need any Javacript - just some basic knowledge about how HTML forms work.

```
<form action="http://example.com/" method="get">
<label for="Store_No">Store_No</label>
<input type="text" id="Store_No" name="Store_No">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The input field gets the proper name set, that of the parameter we want to see in the target URL.

Type "123" into the form field, press "Go" - and it will take you to `http://example.com/?Store_No=123`

Comment: For some reason all I changed was the URL in the action and now the text is placed ion the middle of the URL right after the first slash /.

Comment: What? Please show exactly what you changed.