# Add parameters to url with onSubmit using a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add html parameters to the url with onsubmit. I have 2 forms(1 GET, 1 POST), want to use 1 button to submit them both(Using the POST form button) When the submit button is pressed use onSubmit to call a javascript function, where parameters are "appended" to the url.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
function onSubmitForm() {
    url = "localhost:8080/test/index.php?Title=document.getElementsByName('title')[0].value";
    //I don't know how to actually call the url.
}
```

**EDIT**

I got what I wanted:
[Appending form input value to action url as path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128361/appending-form-input-value-to-action-url-as-path)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to concatenate the string's static and dynamic parts. Then, you can redirect.

```
function onSubmitForm() {
  window.location = "localhost:8080/test/index.php?Title=" + 
    document.querySelector('title').textContent;
}
```

**NOTES:**

- Only form fields have a `.value` property. If you are trying to get
  the text within an element, you can use `.textContent`.
- `.getElementsByName()` scans the entire document and makes a
  collection of all the matching elements. That's wasteful when you
  know you want only the first one and, in the case of `<title>`, there
  is only ever going to be one of those in a document anyway. Use
  `.querySelector()` to locate just the first matching element.

Comment: Can't seem to get it working. I had the code done, It was 3 lines of code yet I somehow managed to delete it. It was a stackoverflow post that I got it from and now that I've looked everyone is suggesting window.location which isn't working in my case and I unfortunately can't get it working. Thanks anyway tho.

Comment: @CrimzonWeb You need to make sure that this code runs ***after*** the entire HTML document has been parsed. As such, place this code into a `<script>` element and insert that element just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`). As long as your `<title>` element has a value, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

***ES6***

**NOTES :**

- Don't forget to use Babel for converting your code in ES5.

I purpose to you this solution :

```js
function onSubmitForm() {
  window.location = `localhost:8080/test/index.php? Title=${document.querySelector('title').textContent}`
}
```

This way of doing with backtick is even simpler than in ES5, let me explain, before we had to concatenate with the sign `+ ourVariable +` the continuation of our string of character.

Here we have more of that. And we can write on several lines as well.
Then `${}` is used to pass a variable inside

Documentation if you want : [Literal template string](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings)

Comment: This is not an answer. It doesn't explain what is being done and why.

Comment: You explain why on your response. I thinking it's important to know the good pratice with ES6 :)

Comment: What if my answer gets removed? Then, how helpful is your answer?

Comment: This is a little better, but it would be best to include a link to the documentation on ES6 templated strings. Answers should always be as complete as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166059/discussion-between-kolacaine-and-scott-marcus).