# form input reload page with appended url

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, append

I have the following form posted on a wordpress page.

I´d like to catch users without referrers  to set the referrer on their own (that referrer part is all handled by a plugin... does not matter here).

The registration form Url is like:

http://myurl.com/register/

The code below just works fine. Inserted directly into the wp page editor (text). 
Except it creates a Url like follows:

http://myurl.com/**register/?id=testinput**

How do i get the resulting Url to be formatted this way?:

http://myurl.com/**register/sp/testinput**

```html
<h3>Your ID</h3>
<p>Please input your ID</p>

<form id = "submit_id_form" onsubmit="myIDFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>

<?php
function myIDFunction(){
    var action_src = "http://myurl.com/register/" + document.getElementsByName("id")[0].value;
    var submit_id_form = document.getElementById('submit_id_form');
    submit_id_form.action = action_src ;
} ?>

</script>
```

This is the original form code (reference below) i`m  trying to modify:

```
<form id = "your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
<input type="text" name="keywords">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

```
function yourFunction(){
var action_src = "http://localhost/test/" + 
document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value;
var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
your_form.action = action_src ;
} 

</script>
```

I tried to append the /sp/ part and remove the appended question mark "?" in the code above.. but i´m totally stuck with coding. (I´m a "clicker" not a coder so to speak)

Thank you very much guys and gals :)

[Original Code is from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128361/appending-form-input-value-to-action-url-as-path)

Comment: You are writing JavaScript code within php tags, I don't think that can work like this

Comment: Also your JavaScript code incorrect, you taken form in 'submit_id_form' variable, then from where your_from var came?

Comment: Updated the original question, including code reference. Don´t know, but on a wordpress page the code is working (but only if inside PHP tags)

Comment: If anyone wonders: Above code technically works in WordPress pages and it is setting a new referral Url and cookie from the form input .. but still the URL formatting is wrong(ly displayed in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

You have to return true from method called on onsubmit as

```
function yourFunction(){ 
var action_src = "http://localhost/test/" + document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value; 
var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form'); 
your_form.action = action_src ;
return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! However i did not notice any difference.. but if that is the right format, i will use it of course. How to get the output formatted now? From ?id=testinput to /sp/testinput

Comment: Is 'testinput' the value you are entering in textbox? If so then on form submit URL will be http://localhost/test/testinput , then you just have to replace test with sp

Comment: Exactly. This is what i thought and tried.. but it does not take that /sp/ and is always appending with ? question mark. Is there maybe a rewrite rule in play? It doesn't even matter if i change domain to localhost or google.com .. it always appends as above.

Comment: Well, this is how form submit work and it'll never append query string  to it, you can check in network tab of browser console

Comment: If it's doing that on server, then you can't fix that with JavaScript

Comment: Oh well.. is there any other way to get this (append user input to url) done. I mean something easy, that even i can do myself?

Comment: If your problem related to form submit URL in JavaScript, you can confirm it in browser console(press f12), network tab, see the request URL

Comment: But what I suspect is that you are changing some other piece of code and checking it at some other place

Comment: Suspected that too.. so changed text to be sure. console says GET .. that ?=xyz appended url and cookie values.. hmm guess everything from now on will be out of scope of that original question. Thank you very much for your help anyways!