# Is there a way to pass text field value to backend by exposing in URL

Tags: html, post, jakarta-ee, get

I'm setting up a new project and I want to send my data exposed in URL.

I tried with exposing the name of the HTML element, bud did not work.

````
```HTML
<form  action="/details/comp">
  <input type="text" name="comp" placeholder="Enter student ID"> 
  <button type="submit()" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
</form>
```
````

Whenever a user enters his id or comp in the text box it should be exposed as it is.
EX: If user enters 2345 in text box, URL should be Localhost:8080/details/2345

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128361/appending-form-input-value-to-action-url-as-path

Comment: @Akash : I tried the one you suggested , it works fine.
But is there any way in which we can avoid calling a function and directly try to expose in URL.
Like for ex,  "/details/comp" and the "comp" gets replaced by user input once he clicks on submit?

Comment: You cannot do this without a JS method call because when form is submitted it submits all the value inside request body not in url path, however one short solution could be

<button type="submit"  onclick="location.href='/details/'+document.getElementById('studentInputBoxId').value;"> Search</button>