# How to use search URL on all pages?

Tags: php, url, search

I use the code below for simple search and it works well in index.php but because i added the code in header.html for include in all pages and the code result work only in index.php.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131517/5227465

index.php?text=keyword = ok
otherpage.php?text=keyword = here not work because search Processing only in index.php

I think the problem in this element means the current page that contains the code:
 (document.getElementById)

```
<form id = "your_form" onsubmit="yourFunction()">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

function yourFunction(){
    var action_src = "http://localhost/test/" + document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value;
    var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
    your_form.action = action_src ;
}
```

any help?

Answer (score -1):

I didnt test it but try this:

```
function yourFunction(){
    var action_src = "http://localhost/test/<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ''); ?>" + document.getElementsByName("keywords")[0].value;
    var your_form = document.getElementById('your_form');
    your_form.action = action_src ;
}
```

Comment: I just saw that you include it in the header. This wont work with my solution.

Comment: yes i test it now work thank you  i want url like this in all pages : http://localhost/test/index.php?keyword=txtinput

Comment: @Deniz maybe you can explain a little bit how your answer should work. I also advise you to read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @rcweb If this is working you should accept this as an answer. ;)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: I just did add the current filename into the javascript code. basename — Returns trailing name component of path. And `__FILE__` is the path. But as said before, this will not work for rcweb because he is including the javascript from another file. Because of that `__FILE__` will output the included filename.

Comment: You can read about here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php and here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php