# How to set a parameter at the end of my URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms

I have a form at Contact Forms 7 to get my clients to receive a call in 30 minutes.
A guy built us a API that does the job. But I need to add the phone number automatically to the end of the external URL (not my contact page nor the thank you page). When submitted, the form redirects to a 'thank you page' and should fire a javascript that sets the phone number at the end of the URL.

Im new to Javascript but I've tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128361/appending-form-input-value-to-action-url-as-path) by [prieston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3769370/prieston), but i don't really know what I'm doing. Can anyone help?

I've also tried the [CF7 to Webhook](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-to-zapier/) but it didnt work.

Comment: You still need CF7 to tell your thank-you page what the phone number was, or you'll lose it, right? Is the thank-you page supposed to load the external URL with the phone number on it?

Comment: I can add a plug in to save the data from the form. I need to form to redirect to the thank you page while firing the javascript to set the phone number from the phone field to the end of the external url. this way the api makes the call automatically.

Comment: Ok, where is this external url? is it in a link somewhere, or in some other javascript on the form page or thank-you page? When in the process do you need to interact with it?

Comment: This https://contactform7.com/dom-events/ has a way to fire some javascript when the form is submitted. If you have the ability to add some javascript to your page somewhere, that could be the key

Comment: Only when the form adds the phone to the end of the url.

Comment: I can add the javascritp. But I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Ok. I can help you write the javascript if you'll tell me where the external url is. Is it in a javascript file? On the page somewhere? Or is it nowhere and you just need to send a request to a specific url? Like `https://www.external.com/process?phone=3215555765`?

Comment: lets say its something like this: http://voice.com.br/sendMessage/numberGoesHere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to make it work with Javascript/AJAX with the following code.

```
    var url = "https://www.urloftheAPI.com";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

var data = `{  
    "phone": "[phone]",
    "id": "company's id in the system of the api"
}`;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(data);
   }};

xhr.send(data);
```

The code was fired with the plug-in  [Redirection for Contact Form 7 by Qube One](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/).

The redirection to a 'thank you page' was made with the same plugin.

Comment: If you use this solution, mind that some of the code might have to be adapted and changed according to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Contact Form 7 events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/#list-of-custom-dom-events).

So something like this will fire when the form is submitted.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    const phone = document.getElementById('phone').value; // Your phone field id
    const external_url = `http://external/?phone=${phone}` // Your page after the form is submitted
    location.replace(external_url) // Load the page with added parameter
  }, false );
```

Comment: The paramenter is to be added to the end of another external URL, not the URL of the thank you page nor the contact page.

Comment: Just change the url to the external one. See edits above.

Comment: Is the problem that you need to call the url, but not send the user there?

Comment: Also. But I can't seem to make the code work.

Comment: Thank you for the help @harceo. I couldn't use your code, but managed with another solution posted by me as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
  var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
 
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( 'phone' == inputs[i].name ) {
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://voice.com.br/sendMessage/"+inputs[i].value);
      iframe.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      break;
    }
  }
}, false );
```

That would create a hidden iframe which will load the url. Then it should still be able to redirect the user to the thank-you page afterward.

Comment: Obviously, you'll need to change `'phone'` to whatever the input name is for their phone number.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I couldn't use your code, but managed with another solution posted as an answer.